# Visualizing the difference between two points with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

***I want to visualize the difference between two points with a line/bar in ggplot2.***

Suppose we have some data on income and spending as a time series.
We would like to visualize not only them, but the balance (=income - spending) as well.
Furthermore, we would like to indicate whether the balance was positive (=surplus) or negative (=deficit).

I have tried several approaches, but none of them produced a satisfying result. Here we go with a reproducible example.

```
# Load libraries and create LONG data example data.frame
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(year  = rep(2000:2009, times=3),
                 var   = rep(c("income","spending","balance"), each=10),
                 value = c(0:9, 9:0, rep(c("deficit","surplus"), each=5)))
df
```

**1.Approach with LONG data**

Unsurprisingly, it doesn't work with LONG data,
because the `geom_linerange` arguments `ymin` and `ymax` cannot be specified correctly. `ymin=value, ymax=value` is definately the wrong way to go  (expected behaviour). `ymin=income, ymax=spending` is obviously wrong, too (expected behaviour).

```
df %>% 
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=value, colour=var)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x=year, ymin=value, ymax=value, colour=net))

#>Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "spread"
```

**2.Approach with WIDE data**

I almost got it working with WIDE data. 
The plot looks good, but the legend for the `geom_point(s)` is missing (expected behaviour).
Simply adding `show.legend = TRUE` to the two geom_point(s) doesn't solve the problem as it overprints the `geom_linerange` legend. Besides, I would rather have the `geom_point` lines of code combined in one (see 1.Approach).

```
df %>% 
  spread(var, value) %>% 
ggplot() + 
  geom_linerange(aes(x=year, ymin=spending, ymax=income, colour=balance)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=spending), colour="red", size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=income), colour="green", size=3) +
  ggtitle("income (green) - spending (red) = balance")
```

[image: 2.Approach]

**3.Approach using LONG and WIDE data**

Combining the 1.Approach with the 2.Approach results in yet another unsatisfying plot. The legend does not differentiate between balance and var (=expected behaviour).

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=(df %>% filter(var=="income" | var=="spending")),
             aes(x=year, y=value, colour=var)) +
  geom_linerange(data=(df %>% spread(var, value)), 
                 aes(x=year, ymin=spending, ymax=income, colour=balance))
```

### [image: 3.Approach]

- *Any (elegant) way out of this dilemma?*
- *Should I use some other `geom` instead of `geom_linerange`?*
- *Is my data in the right format?*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how exactly the legend should look like.

Comment: o "income"   o "spending"       | "surplus"  | "deficit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ggplot(df[df$var != "balance", ]) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(x = year, y = value, fill = var), 
        size=3, pch = 21, colour = alpha("white", 0)) +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(x = year, ymin = income, ymax = spending, colour = balance), 
        data = spread(df, var, value)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

Output:
[image]

The main idea is that we use two different types of aesthetics for colours (`fill` for the points, with the appropriate `pch`, and `colour` for the lines) so that we get separate legends for each.